# Simple regular expression not working

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to match a string with a regular expression but it is not working.

What I am trying to do is simple, it is the typical situation when an user intruduces a range of pages, or single pages. I am reading the string and checking if it is correct or not.

Expressions I am expecting, for a range of pages are like:  `1-3, 5-6, 12-67`

Expressions I am expecting, for single pages are like: `1,5,6,9,10,12`

This is what I have done so far:

```
pagesOption1 = re.compile(r'\b\d\-\d{1,10}\b')
pagesOption2 = re.compile(r'\b\d\,{1,10}\b')
```

Seems like the first expression works, but not the second.

And, would it be possible to merge both of them in one single regular expression?, In a way that, if the user introduces either something like `1-2, 7-10` or something like `3,5,6,7` the expression will be recogniced as good.

Comment: To make your problem simpler, you should specify if its one _or_ the other _or_ mixed, and if it the string contains only these two forms.

Comment: And I wouldn't accept answers if it doesn't accomplish what you really intend to do, otherwise you get no more help if it's only a partial answer to your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This regex should work -

```
^(?:(\d+\-\d+)|(\d+))(?:\,[ ]*(?:(\d+\-\d+)|(\d+)))*$
```

Demo [here](http://regex101.com/r/yA5oZ1)

Testing this -

```
>>> test_vals = [
            '1-3, 5-6, 12-67',
            '1,5,6,9,10,12',
            '1-3,1,2,4',
            'abcd',
        ]
>>> regex = re.compile(r'^(?:(\d+\-\d+)|(\d+))(?:\,[ ]*(?:(\d+\-\d+)|(\d+)))*$')
>>> for val in test_vals:
    print val
    if regex.match(val) == None:
        print "Fail"
    else:
        print "Pass"


1-3, 5-6, 12-67
Pass
1,5,6,9,10,12
Pass
1-3,1,2,4.5
Fail
abcd
Fail
```

Comment: Thanks Yeah for your help, very usefull to understand regular expressions

Comment: why have you introduced capture groups if only validation is required? also, `[ ]*` is better expressed as `\s*` to allow for tabs and any other whitspace characters.

Comment: There is no need, But I used that while testing the regex.

Comment: ah ok I understood it

Comment: @user2919052: Kindly accept his answer if it helped you out. You already have 5 questions, 2 of which have valid answers, and you still haven't accepted anything.

Answer (score 3):

### Simpler is better

Matching the entire input isn't *simple*, as the proposed solutions show, at least it is not as simple as it could/should be. Will become *read only* very quickly and probably be scrapped by anyone that isn't regex savvy when they need to modify it with a simpler more explicit solution.

### Simplest

First parse the entire string and `.split(",");` into individual data entries, you will need these anyway to process. You have to do this anyway to parse out the useable numbers.

Then the test becomes a very simple, test.

```
^(\d+)(?:-\(d+))?$
```

It says, that there the string must start with `one or more digits` and be followed by `optionally a single` - `and one or more digits` and then the string must end.

This makes your logic as simple and maintainable as possible. You also get the benefit of knowing exactly what part of the input is wrong and why so you can report it back to the user.

*The capturing groups are there because you are going to need the input parsed out to actually use it anyway, this way you get the numbers if they match without having to add more code to parse them again anyway.*

Comment: This is by far the best maintainable and idiomatic way of doing it, lengthy regular expressions become *read only* very quickly. Especially for someone coming behind you later that doesn't understand it, they will just re-implement it in a simpler way, costing time and introducing risk.